# Finding inverse laplace of a rational polynomial function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I've been looking at this problem for a few hours now and can't figure out a way to solve it.  Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks for any help.
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\{\frac{(2s^2+9s+11)}{(s^3+5s^2+9s+5)}\}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Do a partial fraction expansion, yielding:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left({\dfrac{2s^2+9s+11}{s^3+5s^2+9s+5}} \right) = \mathcal{L}^{-1} \left( \dfrac{2}{s+1} + \dfrac{1}{s^2 + 4 s + 5}\right)$$

This reduces to:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} \left(\dfrac{2}{s+1} + \dfrac{1}{(s-(-2))^2 + 1^2}\right)$$

Now, use a [*Table of Laplace Transforms*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) or use the definitions to find the inverse.

Comment: You are very welcome! Regards

Comment: @Amzoti: Have a very colorful slumber to night. Thanks.

Comment: Everything the OP needs, all in one post! TU w/G! +

Comment: I just noted my failure to actually click on the uparrow! Glad I noticed, as I missed your comment! Now corrected!